# Still have a question about [topic]: it doesn't always work

Tags: feature-request, documentation, documentation-topics

I know some questions have been asked about this before, but I believe this one is different.

The sentence "Still have a question about [topic]" just doesn't always work with the name of the topic.

**HTML: (you should have a question about HTML, not about the act of getting started with HTML)**

[image]

**SQL: (this sentence looks like it contains a grammar error)**

[image]

**JavaScript: (this one doesn't even show that the question should be about JavaScript)**

[image]

Do we really need this sentence to contain the name of the topic? Typographically, the capital letter at the start of the topic's name is already weird. But more importantly, if the topic's title doesn't make sense at the end of this sentence, or suggests asking off-topic questions.

Why not replace it with a simple "Still have questions?" or "Did you not find what you were looking for?"

Comment: `Not quite what you needed? [Ask Question]`?

Comment: Still have a question about asking questions? [Ask Meta Question]

Answer (score 26):

## Yes.

This should probably be changed.

However, the thing is, improvement requests can be just as good, if the question is trivial to answer. It should be something like this:

> Still confused? You can <kbd>request improvement</kbd>, or you can <kbd>ask about it in Q&A</kbd>.

Comment: That's actually what I meant

Comment: Ah, you meant "it contains the topic name" and not "it's there", I presume?

Comment: You may want to edit your answer now that I edited the question